# Building/compilation with higher level SDK

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm a bit confused with one thing, look:

1. Let's say we have source tree with `<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>` declared in manifest
2. I'm compiling those sources with SDK level 3 (SDK3.apk)
3. Then I'm building sources with SDK level 10 (SDK10.apk)

What will be the difference between these 2 APK's? (SDK3.apk and SDK10.apk) I mean I'm asking not about technical details which libraries will use those APK, I'm asking about APK's behaviour on different devices with different OS'. And which one is better to use?

**Update** My project contains nothing special: make use of SQLite, screen off and SD dismount broadcast interception, usage of some telephony functions. Everything is within SDK level 3 functions/methods. I have both tested with SDK3.APK and SDK10.APK on different devices (older and brand new ones) - looks like workable, but still there's question.

Comment: I am not sure how you get 2 different apk-s with the single `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>`

Comment: Nope, I have compared them - and they're different!

Comment: The question you are asking is vague. Which one is better to use depends on circumstance. In regard to behaviour, there are some clear differences and I would happy to touch on those, but again, without details about your project, the question to too broad to provide a reliable answer. Behaviour will always depend upon which classes you are using and how you are using them... Since there are so many classes within the Android Platform, this is tough to target. Maybe you could provide some information about your project, so that we can answer more effectively?

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic if answer depends on project - that means we're all in big trouble... Why there's no clear instruction what level SDK should be used? And how it's related to minSDKVersion? Anyway - see updates to my question

Comment: I still dont understand 100%. Same source files, you change the eclipse/project properties/android build target, and you get different .apk files?

Comment: @DanielFekete Same source, I change only Android SDK version used to build project and get 2 different apks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, without regard to the UI classes, licensing (if any), and Layout classes, the following information can be provided.

SQLite received a number of small optimizations but nothing major. In particular, all of the previous functionality was kept intact and none of the general behaviors changed.

Telephony changed considerably. There is no argument that Telephony is more responsive the further we move forward in Android. From a Telephony standpoint, API 10 is much better. The reason for this was that many apps were unintentionally inhibiting incoming and outgoing calls. With the API 10, it is harder to do this unintentionally and apps generally receive better, more accurate information about calls in a more efficient manner. (And no, it is not simply due to processor and memory upgrades).

SD instructions became less restrictive as time progressed, and while writes and reads became easier, they also *seemed* to be slightly more faulty (depending on the phone). However, as long as you followed the guidelines, you should be fine. The Android documentation is pretty good about telling you how you should handle your data.

**Now, for the stuff they don't tell you**
The general opinion is that as the APIs have increased, fewer hacks are needed to make your apps consistent across multiple phones. This is actually not the case. It is simply the knowledge about proper use of the platform propagating amongst its community members. For instance, it is possible to have a hack-less solution for something as "complicated" as a Home Screen, if you know how.

As you bridge more APIs with your code, complications are more common, creating a false need for hacks. This has been true on every piece of software on every platform since specific platform development began. (As an example, people are *still* complaining about support for IE6) Choosing a good point to start is the best practice and indeed program the way Google advises, with some notes.

Google obviously has not thought of all the cool things we can do. Otherwise, they wouldn't need us to make the platform the coolest one out there (IMHO). However, they do tell you how to appropriately use *their* Classes and Interfaces. Follow those guidelines and do your neat stuff "in between" them and your apps will perform well, no matter which API you use.

**Some Other Stuff**
Some of the Activity and View behaviors are significantly improved in API 10, but most of this is in regard to event handling itself, rather than infrastructure. The benefits to using API 10 here are not solidified unless you are handling specific events or binding to data in particular ways.

---

**In Reponse to Your Comment "Why is there no clear answer?"**
The reason why it always depends on the project and your usage is the same reason it has always been. OOP allows you to override and reprogram just about any aspect of any platform you are working with. Furthermore you can create your own implementations of things quite easily. Your imagination and innovation are the key here.

Ever used two pieces of software that have done exactly the same thing and thought "This one is the better of the two?" You have just experienced what I have described. It may be better because you are more familiar with its standards. However, it may also be better because it breaks those conventions in a more intuitive way.

The same thing can exhibit itself when a piece of software you like works on one device/computer, but not an another for no explicable reason. The key to a great piece of software is your insight to the solution, no matter which devices it works on. The key to a successful piece of software (from a customer's perspective) is how consistent the experience is. In other words, how many devices it works on and how many people it works for. I, personally, opt for somewhere in between, even though I love super-shiny solutions. Just because I think a solution is shiny, doesn't mean that my customers may all use my solution and I have to support as many as I can.

**In Response to: "How is it related to minSDKLevel?**
Since the choice of which Android OS levels you are going to support is yours, the answer should be obvious. You are saying that your app can be installed on API 4 all the way through API 10 and you will support ALL of them. This means that your default result APK will have a solution for all of them (if you program it).

If, however, you build for specific versions (like many do with different APKs), then each has its own issues and own support. They may even (in fact, must in many case) have their own market entry. BUT, you SHOULD adjust your manifest for each individual build, if you choose this model so that an API 4 device does not see the API 10 APK, if you have an API 4 specific APK.

---

**Conclusion**
In conclusion, what you can expect largely depends on how well you adhere to Google's guidelines for programming in Android and how inventive you are about bending the rules, but not breaking them. In general, most can expect a more consistent experience in API 10 than in API 3. With that experience is often a smoother response with an equivalently robust data engine. Your UI look and feel depends heavily upon the settings for each Layout and View, and can radically change between devices especially if you are creating all of your View dynamically. API 3 is definitely the more consistent of the two when it comes to handling UI, as API 10 has quite a few more options. I **think** most people would agree that API 10 is probably going to be a more satisfactory experience for your users as a whole.

FuzzicalLogic

P.S. As a note, I develop in API 7 as it has the widest range of supported devices, with a comparable set of options. Anything that is not implemented in 7 but is in 10, I can ultimately override to mimic. This is, however, my preference.

Comment: Thanx for response and your thoughts. I'm using some telephony/SD card functions which are unavailable in level 4 just through Java reflection, such that if requested method is unaccessible in *this* Android - simply using stub otherwise calling method. What d'u think about these kind of hacks?

Comment: Personally, I believe that "hackless" solutions are the best solutions. That being said, there is a time and place for hacks no matter how much one might disagree. Your hacks address wide scale compatibility which is the best possible circumstance for a hack. One ultimately does not want to hack every phone, but hacking for an entire API level may be required and sometimes important.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track and investigating all of the right pieces of info. This question is not really about hacks; you asked about the impacts, so I touched on them as they are a major impact. There are many awesome programmers out there who use hacky solutions and I would hate to turn this question into a debate about which hacks are appropriate and which ones are not and when. :) It would demean the real focus of your question. It is, however, a possible side effect and one that every programmer should be aware  of.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the android.jar which is shiped when your apk file is generated.
When you building source with sdk level 4 then android.jar for sdk level 4 is used to build your apk file same is the case with sdk level 10.

Comment: It's technical answer. I'm asking about difference from usage viewpoint. How these APK's will behave on different devices with different Android OS versions? And which one is more suitable for production release?

Answer (score -1):

Sdk level 10 can not be installed on device having api level lower than 10.
sdk level 4 can not be installed on device having api level lower than 4.
Both apk will behave in same manner on different device having different api levels unless and untill you have not used any deprecated stuff.
For example if method m1 is deprecated after sdk level 5 and you are still using it in sdk level 10 then app will behavior is undefined when execution comes to call of method m1.

Comment: Nope, APK built under SDK level 10 with minSDKVersion=4 can easily be installed on device which uses SDK level 4. It's easy to justify - just try it on emulator and you will see